# How do I perform IO inside of Parsec's monad?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, parsec

I am using Parsec to read through a simple file containing `FilePath`s to other images.

eg.

```
img ../images/test.gif
img ../../gifs/image.png
```

I would like to parse each line one at a time, read the image in as a `ByteString`, and return it wrapped in Parsec's monad. However, a function that looks like:

```
filename <- getName
contents <- BS.readFile fileName
results  <- decodeImage contents
let image = case results of
    Left err -> error $ show err
    Right img -> img
return results
```

throws an error of

```
Couldn't match type `IO' with `ParsecT s0 u0 m0'
Expected type: ParsecT s0 u0 m0 BS.ByteString
  Actual type: IO BS.ByteString
```

I'm not exactly sure how monads work yet - but it seems as if it's wrapping it in the wrong monad? Is there a way I can make this explicit?

Comment: What's the type of `decodeImage`? As a general rule, you should include enough code in your question that it can be compiled.

Comment: It has a type of `ByteString -> IO (Either String Image)` where `Image` is `type Image = Bitmap Word8`. It comes from the Codec.Image.STB library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`liftIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans.html#v:liftIO) from `Control.Monad.Trans` in the `mtl` package to transform the operations on `IO` into `ParsecT s0 u0 IO` :

```
contents <- liftIO $ BS.readFile fileName
results  <- liftIO $ decodeImage contents
```

Comment: (Note I originally said `lift` in this answer then changed it to `liftIO` which is generally more reliable with `IO` computations in monad transformer stacks. Both probably work fine in your specific case)